# ResourcePool.idle() is considering resources in seize blocks as idle

Tags: anylogic

If an agent enters a seize block that seizes 2 resource units each of different pools, if resource unit 1 is seized by that block while resource unit 2 is not because it is currently performing another task, resource unit 1 is considered idle when I use `ResourcePool.idle()`. The problem with this is that in other parts of my model, when I try to set conditions based on if a certain resource unit is not idle (meaning it is busy), it considers the time that resource unit 1 is waiting for the seize of resource unit 2 as idle, when really, I would like it to be busy.

Comment: What do you mean "in another seize block waiting" either a resource is seized or busy or in maintenance.... Can you perhaps add a screenshot of your model?

Comment: I have edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "Seize units one by one" checked.
[image]

Otherwise all units remain idle until one both are available to be seized jointly.